# Discord.py rewrite on_member_join auto assign role

Tags: python, discord.py

I am confused about this auto role assign that I have working yesterday and havent touched it since...

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(ctx, member):
    if member.guild.name == "lusk_245789":  # Server Name

        role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Member")
        await member.add_roles(role)

        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Member Joined", description=f"{member.mention}, Welcome to {member.guild.name}. We hope that your time with us is a happy one!", color=0x9b26b9, font_size=200, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)

        embed.add_field(name="Please check out the Rules Channel!", value="<#822090510495514644>", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Latest announcements are made here!", value="<#781017647922937856>", inline=False)
        embed.set_footer(text="Task Completed!")

        # Send the embed message and fields
        await client.get_channel(873238209897844799).send(embed=embed)

        # Get role and assign to new member

    #elif member.guild.name == "Server Name":
        #embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Welcome {member.name} !\nwelcome to #{member.guild.name}', #color=0x9b26b9)  #you can add more if you want 
        #await client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID).send(embed=embed)
    else:
        return
```

The error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_member_join() missing 1 required positional argument: 'member'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loloToster was half correct, but the other issue was I also forgot to remove the

```
timestamp=ctx.message.created_at
```

within the embed causing issues within my code, I believe that you will be able to use timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow() as a replacement!

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

That's because `on_member_join` event takes only one parameter `member` not `ctx` and `member`. Just replace this:

```py
async def on_member_join(ctx, member):
```

with this:

```py
async def on_member_join(member):
```

and it should work.

Comment: It doesnt help with the issue, I have as I want an embed to be sent of that user when joining aswell